# Should I Use NoSQL Datastore of Kinvey, or Google Cloud Datastore?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, cloud, backend, kinvey

I'm build an android application with Kinvey platform back-end,with BusinessLogic to be based on Google App Engine - using the recent integration between Google and Kinvey -

My question is that would it be better - faster, cheaper & more effecient - to use Kinvey OOTB datastore collection, or should I implement the data model layer of the application with Google Cloud Datastore ?! and if I started with Kinvey now, would it be easy to migrate later to Google Cloud Datastore upon need ?!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think we'd need a bit more detail about how you're designing your application to answer this for you...

If you're using App Engine for your application logic, it stands to reason that you might want to store your data there too (this let's you do things like... offline operations on data using an [App Engine module](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/)). If you do that, you'll have to write your own API handlers on App Engine to process requests from your mobile app.

Hope that helps, feel free to delete if not.